# Inclusion symbol

Tags: symbols

I need this symbols used by Boole and Peirce, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\inclusion{\ooalign{$-$\cr$<$}}
\begin{document}
$\inclusion$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on how it is used, you can wrap it in a `\mathrel` for example.

If you need it across math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\inclusion{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle-$\cr$\SavedStyle<$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\inclusion_{\inclusion_{\inclusion}}$

$ X\inclusion B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Look, Mom!  I didn't use `stackengine`!!

Answer (score 4):

The ⪪ symbol is U+2AAA in Unicode, and `\smt` in the `unicode-math` package.  It’s not present in the default Latin Modern Math font, but it is in several others.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\( S \smt T \)
\end{document}
```

[image: S ⪪ T]

In legacy PDFTeX documents, it’s available from the `stix` or `stix2` package.